# CSS file doesn't load, trying to test an app on Google App Engine locally

Tags: html, css, google-app-engine

I am very new to CSS.

I am putting the following line in the header of my html, but CSS doesn't load:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/main.css" />
```

Basically my HTML doesn't see the CSS file. I am probably missing a very obvious point. My CSS file is in the "static" folder of my project and my HTML file is in the "templates" folder.

While writing this, I realized that I might be directing to the wrong path, but changing it to "../static/main.css" didn't help either.

Should I use SRC instead of HREF, when using this locally? Or is it something completely different?

Thank you for your help!

UPDATED:
The project tree is as follows:

```
|____.gitignore
|____app.yaml
|____appblog.py
|____appblog.pyc
|____README.md
|____static
| |____main.css
|____templates
| |____front.html
| |____newpost.html
```

I am linking to main.css from inside my front.html

Comment: Is the static folder in the templates folder? If not, then it won't work.

Comment: Do you get any error in DevTools?

Comment: No, you do NOT have to use the `src` attribute. Please show your directory structure with including files or check this again. Refresh the site with Ctrl+F5 after you have made changes like this. Ctrl+F5 forces the browser to reload all resources.

Comment: So, should I move the static folder into templates folder? is there any other way to make it work?

Comment: `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../static/main.css" />`...you need to add the `../` to back it up one directory, then go into the `static` directory.

Comment: what is the url of your page? did you load templates with your python code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving the wrong route to the CSS file.  It is currently looking for the file in `templates/static/main.css`, which doesn't exist.  You need to add `../` to back out of the `templates` directory, and then head to the `static` directory.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/main.css">
```

If the directory structure is in your root directory, you could also link relative to root by adding `/`.  This will start in the root directory, and then look for the `static` directory.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/main.css">
```

Also, make sure you are adding that in the `head` of the document.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer this, Matthew. 
Actually, I tried both of those solutions before and they didn't work. My third solution was to move the `static` directory to `templates` but so far that hasn't worked either. I will keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was somewhere else:
I am using `Google App Engine` for the app development and I should've included the following under `-handlers`:

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

Thank you for all your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome browser: Open developer tool (F12) and look at right top of the panel, or click "Console" tab, if the develper tool console return Not found error with your main.css file then check your css path. You can try to locate html file and css file in one directory and then change link tag to 
Can you show me how did you open the html file? direct click on the html or browse through webserver project?